# How to add a submit form in post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms

Actually I want to create a plugin for wordpress and in my custom post type, I wan to create a popup which I append a div element on on document.body. In the document.body there is no form element available, when I checked the code of the web page with firebug, the form element on the web page only exist in the metabox. So, how could I do to add a file upload field to my div.

Comment: Show us your code and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: Use this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/ for uploading file from post. You can use this plugin with COntact form 7 too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: i am sure this will helps you completely

[Contact Form](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/&ei=5PpkUq7jEs3_rAfO8oFI&usg=AFQjCNF6GygEqxMJItw_5Fy9-AoaHnSC8w&bvm=bv.54934254,bs.1,d.bmk)

Thanks